# Best way to indicate what configuration values are needed by a library

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config

- You implement a Library called `LogLibrary` which needs configuration values,
- To retrieve the configuration values you implement your own `System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler`,
- So in the `App.config` file of the Program using `LogLibrary`, you want to find something like:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="LogLibrary" type="Class, Namespace"/>
    </configSections>
    <LogLibrary>
        <!-- Directory where daily log files will be created. -->
        <LogDirectory>C:\Logs</LogDirectory>
        <!-- Insert other values here -->
    </LogLibrary>
</configuration>
```

Question: What is the best way to indicate to the users of the `LogLibrary` what needs to be present in `App.config` ?

I personally provide a `README.txt` file (included in the Library's VS project) with the Library. But i find this solution to be "amateur". Do you guys have better practices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not need a readme.txt, just include an app.config in your library with sample values as you have shown above and mention this in the documentation. Developers will notice this either in your source file or in the documentation you provide online or offline and will copy that section (same as above) in their app.config or web.config.

This is how it normally goes for Log4Net, that you google and find examples on their websites.

Comment: The advantage of adding an App.config over a simple text file only is, to me, syntax highlighting. Though this is a HUGE advantage, the idea is still the same.

Comment: not really because when you build you will generate the mydllname.dll and the mydllname.dll.config and just puth both in the bin subfolder when you distribute your library even without source code; users will notice the .config and will use it copying from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

In .NET world `.config` files are idiomatic way of configuring applications/libraries, so actual location is pretty much a given. As for configuration section layout nothing can beat thorough documentation of your project (rare nowadays, however). Think [NLog Configuration File](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file).

Comment: I'd rather add documentation about configuration values directly in the sample configuration file. This way the end-user immediately understands each configuration value. Of course this is true for simple libraries. For more complex ones (as NLog, which can load its configuration from different places), I fully agree on the dedicated documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the library to throw an exception when loading the configuration with detailed information about what configuration errors are present. As with any library you should of course also supply proper documentation, in which the configuration requirements can be detailed.

Comment: The library throwing exceptions only provides "runtime documentation" to the user of the Library. In my opinion the configuration details should be available in an other place than simply in an exception Message.

Comment: Yes, and I stated that also. Any good library should supply proper documentation.